# How can I get substring of object property in ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view which will display a username. The username is a property of the object the view is strongly typed to.

my username is formatted as such `domain\usernametext`

So i want to get the substring of MyModel.username beginning after the last index of `\`

I tried this but it gives me an invalid operation exception at runtime:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserName.Substring(x.UserName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1))
```

Comment: If this is something you're going to do several times or in different places, a Template might be the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with an HTML Helper.

You can do

```
@Model.Username.Substring(Model.UserName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
```

to get it to print out. Or you can

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", 
   Model.Username.Substring(Model.UserName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 string str = "AA-22-123456";

 string substr=str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("-")+1);
```

Result : 123456